# SORT BY navigational menu options show twice in magento page

Tags: magento

my website shows the SORT BY navigational menu TWICE on certain pages.

Click [here](http://www.musicuncle.com/live-sound/mixers.html)!
This page shows SORT BY menu twice.

Click [here](http://www.musicuncle.com/live-sound.html)!
This page shows SORT BY menu correctly.

Please tell me how can i fix this issue?

Comment: I can c proper two sort by per page u mentioned above . . .

Answer (score 1):

This is probably declared twice, once in the core layout xml and once in your theme's module file (in my case often local.xml / themename.xml)... In your case these declerations can be found under your category page declaration.